# Add CDATA section to document xerces-c

Tags: c++, xml, cdata, xerces-c

I am creating a `XML` document using `xerces-c` in `C++`. The problem I am facing is I need to include a `cdata` section in the document. I have found a function `createCDATASection` for that. But its return value is of type `DOMCDATASection` and the `AppendChild` fuction accepts argument of type `DOMNode`. Is casting to be used here? Or is there some other way.

Comment: According to https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMCDATASection.html DOMCDATASection inherits from DOMNode so no casting needed

Comment: @systemcpro : On directly using, I get the error as ` error C2664: 'xercesc_3_1::DOMNode *xercesc_3_1::DOMNode::appendChild(xercesc_3_1::DOMNode *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'xercesc_3_1::DOMCDATASection *' to 'xercesc_3_1::DOMNode *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`

Comment: We converted all our models to use xerces because of the validation. Its a bout a year ago and although I don't remember much about the implementation details, I do know that there is not one single dynamic_cast in the code. I wonder if we are looking at the same API? Have a look at this link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/xml/x-xercc2/sidefile2.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just didn't add all the necessary include statements.
Please make sure that (at least) the following line is included.

```cpp
#include "xercesc\dom\DOMCDATASection.hpp"
```

Then the following code compiles correctly.

```cpp
XMLCh* data = XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_QUALIFIER XMLString::transcode("foo");
XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_QUALIFIER DOMCDATASection* pData = pDoc->createCDATASection(data);
pDoc->getDocumentElement()->appendChild(pData);
```